# eclipse javascript syntax error on hashbang line

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, syntax-error

when I import some existing node.js code into the eclipse workspace, it complains with

*Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", delete this token*

on the `#! /usr/bin/env/node` hashbang line.

How can I tell eclipse to ignore this error?

Answer (score 0):

With Nodeclipse 0.7 and JSHint Integraton, it is now general question "How to configure JSHint" for that.

see [How to ignore node shebang error in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960201/how-to-ignore-node-shebang-error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to this question!  Remove jsdt nature from your Eclipse .project file.  Keep node nature.

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

See also: [How to ignore node shebang error in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960201/how-to-ignore-node-shebang-error-in-eclipse).

Also, if you do not have node nature, install the nodeclipse plugin.  It's great!