# How to ignore node shebang error in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, jshint, jsdt, nodeclipse

I am writing some node command line utilities.  They all start with the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

With Eclipse Juno and the Nodeclipse Node.js plugin, this line of code produces an error as shown:

[image: Node shebang eclipse error]

OK, so `#` is not a valid comment character in javascript, but it is a valid character in Linux/UNIX as the **shebang** of the first line in a file.  But how can I set up Eclipse to ignore this error?  This is a problem for me because code formatting does not work if you have errors.  I have to delete the line.  Hit <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-F</kbd> and add the line back.

I have tried a lot of things and researched, but I can't find an answer.

There is a duplicate question out there, [eclipse javascript syntax error on hashbang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192446/eclipse-javascript-syntax-error-on-hashbang-line), but my question has more info.

#### EDIT:

Looks like there was something added to [jshint to allow shebangs in the first line](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/66).  Maybe I need to update my node-eclipse, or maybe the node-eclipse project needs to update jshint?

- My jshint eclipse integration is version 0.9.6.
- My nodeclipse is 0.4.0.20130519...

I upgraded to

- jshint eclipse integration 0.9.9.20131029
- nodeclipse 0.7.0.20131101

That did not help.

Here is my JSHint version in eclipse:

[image]

#### EDIT 2:

Thanks for the answer VonC.  But I think this shows that I do not have a BOM in the file.  Any other ideas?

```
$ od -N 20 -t x1 hello.js
0000000 23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 6e
0000020 6f 64 65 0a
0000024
```

#### EDIT 3:

With regard to Paul Verest's answer below, I tried to turn off JSDT validation, but I can't seem to do it.  I unchecked "Enable JavaScript semantic validation" (In Eclipse, see Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Validator > Errors/Warnings), but the issue remains.

I am now uninstalling **Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.4.2**. That did not seem to help and now my CSS and HTML editors are gone.  Now I have tried to disable JSDT validation by following some of the ideas in this SO question, [How do I remove javascript validation from my eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project).

So I went into my project properties and went to JavaScript > Validation.  I have set everything to "Enabled project specific settings" and unchecked "Errors/Warnings", "JSDOC", etc.  Even so, I think validation is still running since the problem persists!  My "Builders" Properties only lists the "JSHint Problem Checker" which is enabled.  (I am doing all this on a new test project with a hello.js).

#### EDIT 4, THE ANSWER

It was not easy, but I ended up hacking the .project file in Eclipse.  I had this:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

I removed the jsdt nature and now the error on the shebang line is GONE!  I did this in my test project and my real project.  It worked!  This is actually pretty helpful since I can format the file and I'm actually running jshint now.

Comment: I take it by the up votes that this is a problem for other people too.

Comment: For Cordova - remove platforms/android/cordova with js exlude path : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 option for JavaScript validation in Eclipse:

- JSDT
- JSHint (default since Nodeclipse 0.7)

As configration is stored per project, copy .* settings files from project created with 0.7 or re-configure it manually (just compare .* files with newly created project).
Then put .jshintrc file like 
https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates/.jshintrc

Try to check [JSHint options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/), if it is possible.

Note that with JSHint usage, ~~this question becomes general JSHint question (not Eclipse or Nodeclipse related).~~

UPDATE:

`.project` content since 0.7 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.eclipsesource.jshint.ui.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

As @Jess discovered this was error shown by JSDT, not JSHInt,
so removing `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>` will stop JSDT from displaying it (even with JavaScript semantic validation already turned off since 0.7)

UPDATE 3:

Drawback of `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>` removed will be that code assist and click-though to definition will not work (It actually works in rare cases when JSDocs are defined e.g. http://www.nodeclipse.org/nodejs/javascript/sources/books/2013/10/22/JSDT-require-JSDoc.html or within 1 .js file)

[image: JSDoc support]

Even click-through to definition
[image: click-through to definition]

Comment: More precise answer than mine. +1

Comment: Thank you!  Please see edits to the question.  I believe that I am finally running JSHint since I see some problems that JSHint will detect, but JSDT will not.  However, the problem remains.  There is still an error on the shebang line.

Comment: Yes, finally solved. Though I don't remember now what would be implication of `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>` removed. It may be that code assist and click-though to definition will not work (It actually works in rare cases when JSDocs are definied http://www.nodeclipse.org/nodejs/javascript/sources/books/2013/10/22/JSDT-require-JSDoc.html)

Comment: I attempted this and i got back the same error with the shebang line

Comment: Then you are likely to be using old Nodeclipse version (latest is 0.11 http://www.nodeclipse.org/history). JSDT is not used for validation, but JSHint-Eclipse. Please create new question or an issue in Nodeclipse if there is need to follow.

Comment: Is the answer that you have to remove the `jsNature` or can one fix the error in JSHint config? The link to https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/common-templates/.jshintrc is dead. Can you please edit to precisely say what is the JSHint [option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) that needs to be set to stop this error?

Comment: To deactivate JSDT's flagging of this error, remove the source files from JSDT's include path in Project Properties > JavaScript > Include Path > Source. Select all the folders and click Remove.

Comment: The link https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates/.jshintrc is not dead, but GitHub sometimes failes to find .jshintrc under https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates

Comment: For your solution please add an answer or start discussion at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues

Answer (score 4):

Update:

The issue entered in nodeclipse points out to [JSHint issue 66](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/66).
As [Paul Verest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482717/paul-verest) remarks in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953433/6309) (upvoted), this could be as simple as making sure JSHint check the code.
Since [commit 63da9](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/63da966cf52d7673001103f9a6871db8b5f84cf5), JSHint knows how to ignore that shebang directive.

```
// If the first line is a shebang (#!), remove it and move on.
// Shebangs are used by Node scripts.
if (lines[0] && lines[0].substr(0, 2) == '#!')
  lines.shift();
```

---

Original answer

Are you sure '`#`' is not a valid character (yet [used in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806572/6309))?

Double-check the encoding of your `node.js` file, because if it is UTF-8 *with* [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), then the javascript couldn't be launched properly.

See "[What's different between utf-8 and utf-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247434/6309)", and the [wikipedia article on shebang (section "Magic number")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Magic_number)

> The shebang characters are represented by the same two bytes in extended ASCII encodings, including UTF-8, which is commonly used for scripts and other text files on current Unix-like systems.
>   However, UTF-8 files may begin with the optional byte order mark (BOM); **if the "`exec`" function specifically detects the bytes `0x23 0x21`, then the presence of the BOM (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`) before the shebang will prevent the script interpreter from being executed**.
>   Some authorities [recommend against using the byte order mark in POSIX (Unix-like) scripts](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5), for this reason and for wider interoperability and philosophical concerns.

Comment: On further thought, I appreciate the attempt, but I don't think this is the answer.  The script runs fine, and jshint running in eclipse seems to be running fine also.  **[jshint](http://www.nodeclipse.org/history)** is detecting the first line as an error since it is not valid javascript.

Comment: @Jess I simply meant: "Is it in UTF-8 *without* BOM, or UTF-8 *with* BOM?" The BOM extra first character could trigger the "invalid token" error message.

Comment: Hi @VonC.  This is a really good idea, but I don't have a BOM.  I edited the question to show the first bytes in HEX.

Comment: It seems that eclipse typical operation is **[no BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905582/working-with-utf-8-files-in-eclipse)** and also **[this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/725818/)**.

Comment: @Jess I see (and agree with my old answer). Perhaps that would be something to mention to https://github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/issues, or rather https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues, unless it is JSHint which is too picky.

Comment: thanks for hanging in there with me.  I reported an issue at github.  We will see what they say:  https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse/issues/3

Comment: +1 for being so darn helpful!  :D  I'm waiting to see the problem solved before marking an answer, but I won't forget.

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet i am having the same issue i had no other choice but to remove my project from JavaScript 'Include Path' in Eclipse