# Eclipse Mars JavaScript Editor not recognizing errors

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt, tern

Somehow i can enter anything i want in a .js file but there are no errors nor warnings (syntax highlighting works tough) recognized.

I have no exludes or something.

Also i remember having the option to convert a project into a javascript project but this option is also gone.

my .project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>JavaScriptProject</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Anyone knows what could be the reason for this?

**Update:**

I have configured Tern ESLint for validation (and converted the project to a tern project) but also Tern ESlint is also showing no errors or warnings. My Guess is that somewhere there must be a setting which deavtivated the JavaScript code validation for JSDT and / or Tern but in the settings and project settings i have checked all i can find regarding validation...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Javascript editor and not just the plain text editor? Right click on the file in Project Explorer and look at what the 'Open With' menu has selected.

Comment: I have configured Eclipse to use JavaScript editor as default for .js and ._js files, also syntax highlighting works.(i checked also the open with dialog)

Comment: Is your source file in something recognized as a Source Folder according to the project's JavaScript Include Path?

Comment: Yes all included no special excludes.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .project file and check if your project has the "jsdt nature".
As described as in "Edit 4" in the Question section of [this post: how-to-ignore-node-shebang-error-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960201/how-to-ignore-node-shebang-error-in-eclipse)

In the answer sections there is quite some information too.

I also recommend to add 'eslint' with the `--fix` option as an External Tool Configuration .

Comment: i have the jsdt line inside the .project but can it be that the jsdt are somehow disabled?